# Stretching specific layers within SVG element

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to create a rather complex SVG interface, composed of several graphical layers.

I want some of the layers (i.e., "g" elements within the SVG) to be stretched when resizing the browser window, by using the viewBox attribute. Other layers in the same SVG should be scaled or handled individually. And that's where i run into problems.

I would have liked to be able to do the following:

```
<svg>
    <g name="stretchable" width="900px" height="500px" viewBox="0px 0px 900px 500px">
        ...insert stretchable shapes here...
    </g>
    <g name="non-stretchable">
        ...insert other shapes here...
    </g>
</svg>
```

...and then stretch the "stretchable" g element only, by manipulating the viewBox attribute. But apparently, the viewBox attribute is not applicable in the g element.

Is there any other way to stretch a specific "g" element within an SVG, and not have to stretch the whole SVG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a `<svg>` element instead of a `<g>` element. It does allow using a viewBox attribute.

If that's no good you could always experiment with adding a transform="scale(x,y)" to the `<g>` element where x and y are numeric scale factors you would need to calculate.

BTW `<g>` elements don't support width or height attributes either although `<svg>` elements do.

Comment: Excellent solution! Especially the transform/scale one. I have been using scale somewhat, but always thought it was a single-value attribute (always preserving aspect ratio). I didn't realize that you could add two values to get a stretched behaviour. I already calculate scale factors and do a lot of transform string manipulation, so I'm going to opt for your transform="scale(x, y)" suggestion. Which of course works like a charm on a <g> element. Great thanks!